# Merging cells in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, cell, html

Is it possible to merge some cells of a JTable object?

[image: merging cells]
<sub>(source: [codeguru.com](http://www.codeguru.com/java/articles/139_table12.gif))</sub>

If it's not possible through JTable what is the best approach. Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not out-of-the-box. [Here is an example](http://codeguru.earthweb.com/java/articles/139.shtml) that supports merging arbitrarty cells. [This page](http://www.crionics.com/products/opensource/faq/swing_ex/JTableExamples4.html) has several examples of tables with spanning cells. Of course it's old and you get what you pay for. If paid software is an option, [JIDE Grids](http://codeguru.earthweb.com/java/articles/139.shtml) has some really nice Swing table support including [custom cell spans](http://www.jidesoft.com/images/cellspantable2.png).

Comment: 3 out of 4 of those URLs are 404. :(

Comment: **-1** and no fix 2 year later :(

Answer (score 2):

You could implement a JTable using a TableModel merging two columns of the original TableModel.

```
class Model2 extends AbstractTableModel
{
private TableModel delegate;
public Model2(TableModel delegate)
 {
 this.delegate= delegate;
 }

public int getRowCount() { return this.delegate.getRowCount();}
public int getColumnCount() { return this.delegate.getColumnCount()-1;}
public Object getValueAt(int row, int col)
 {
 if(col==0) return ""+delegate.getValueAt(row,col)+delegate.getValueAt(row,col+1);
 return delegate.getValueAt(col+1);
 }
(...)
}
```

Comment: I said merging 'cells', not columns.