# Merging cells in a JXTreeTable

Tags: java, swing, merge, cells, jxtable

I want to merge two cells in a JXTreeTable. Is this possible? I have read the solution for [Merging cells in JTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476721/merging-cells-in-jtable), but this does not work for JXTreeTables.

What I mean with merging cells: I want to create a structure like this:

`node 1          | title for 3 cells | title for 3 cells |

  subnode    |  c1  | c2  |  c3  |  c1  | c2  |  c3  |

  subnode    |  c1  | c2  |  c3  |  c1  | c2  |  c3  |`

so the 'title for 3 cells' is created by merging 3 different cells on the same row/node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, per http://www.inf.furb.br/~piva/downloads/compilador/Compilador/Compilador/bibliotecas%20extras/swinglabs-0.8.0-bin/swinglabs/docs/api/org/jdesktop/swingx/JXTreeTable.html and links therefrom, it seems no such "merging" functionality is available in the class itself -- looks to me like you'll just have to do the "merging"-like operations in your app-level code.