# A JTable where number of columns in each row may be different

Tags: java, swing, jtable, row, columnspan

I am looking for a solution for a JTable where I can vary the number of columns in each row, but where the size (in pixels) of the row is constant.

I found stackoverflow referencing so far only dead-links to an old solution:

[JTable with varying number of columns per row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4147843/jtable-with-varying-number-of-columns-per-row)

Is there a newer better way to do it now ? 
If so, what?
If not, does anyone know what the old solution was?

thanks.

Comment: spanning cells is not supported, all those old examples were/are hacks which require tweaking the internals of the ui-delegate - nothing trivial and lots of work. If you can afford it, you might be better off with a commercial solution like JIDE. Just sayin' :-)

Comment: I should note: I can only use java 6. If a new solution requires java7, i'm out of luck, and should stick with whatever the old solution was.

Comment: Although it is not appropriate, if you don't have too many rows in your table, you could consider using a `JPanel` with a `GridBagLayout` which supports col/row span (and many other stuffs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone know what the old solution was?

The examples, which appear to have been created for a Swing beta release in the last millennium, may be found [here](http://www.crionics.com/public/swing_examples/SwingExamples.html). You may be looking for [`MultiSpanCellTable`](http://www.crionics.com/public/swing_examples/JTableExamples4.html). They may be a useful object of study, but they are *not* current. YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a renderer (panel with multiple fixed size labels or even multiple panels for each type of row).

It should be one column in TableModel with the renderer applied.