# JTable BowlingScoreCard

Tags: java, swing

Is there a possibility to implement a bowling score card using a normal JTable? Could I split a Cell in two Textfields? How do I do this?

I want to implement this with a JTable and not with a normal GridBagLayout like ([JTable splitting cells. How to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15291845/jtable-splitting-cells-how-to?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa))

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it possible, yes, do you really want to do it, probably not. Why? Because it's insanely complex and would require you to create your own UI delegate to achieve it.  For some ideas (on how insane it is), you could look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20206578/show-column-header-on-dragging-column/20208995#20208995) which just does column grouping

Comment: @MadProgrammer or could I do this with a TableCellRenderer or is it just the representation of the cell?

Comment: Yes, a single cell, not two, which you’d need them to span multiple columns

Comment: @MadProgrammer How would I do this? Do you have an example for me? Thanks

Comment: Since it’s the ui delegates responsibility to manage the cell/editor placement, you’d need to start there and no, I don’t have an example