# How to merge cell in DefaultTableModel/JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer, jtableheader

I searched a lot and got some answers for this Q. but many of them referred to links which give 404 error.
I want to make table like this:

[image: No. of cells to be merged is not fixed]

Is there any method in java for this?

Comment: In one of my project, I use [that SpanTable](https://code.google.com/p/spantable/source/browse/SpanTable/src/main/java/spantable/?r=b5aa2f0d7bc6e0ced427562dcc22396b41963948). In another I use group header from [that SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11666046/2894369). Try them.

Comment: You should check [this](http://www.java3z.com/cwbwebhome/article/article5/swing_example/JTableExamples4.html) and/or [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/MultiSpanCellTableExample.htm).

Comment: @Qui Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError

Comment: @Qui `setColumnIdentifiers(columnNames);` is causing problem

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[MultiSpanCellTableExample](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/MultiSpanCellTableExample.htm) demonstrates how to merge cells by creating a custom `TableUI`. There seem to be a problem in this example that causes `StackOverflowError`, at least in Java 6. To fix this, inside `AttributiveCellTableModel.setDataVector()` replace:

```
setColumnIdentifiers(columnNames);
```

with:

```
this.columnIdentifiers = columnNames;
```

IE:

```
public void setDataVector(Vector newData, Vector columnNames) {
    if (newData == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "setDataVector() - Null parameter");
    dataVector = new Vector(0);
    // setColumnIdentifiers(columnNames);
    this.columnIdentifiers = columnNames;
    dataVector = newData;

    cellAtt = new DefaultCellAttribute(dataVector.size(),
            columnIdentifiers.size());

    newRowsAdded(new TableModelEvent(this, 0, getRowCount() - 1,
            TableModelEvent.ALL_COLUMNS, TableModelEvent.INSERT));
}
```

The problem is that `setColumnIdentifiers` calls into `setDataVector` hence triggering the `StackOverflowError`. Once fixed, this is how the example looks like:

[image]

There is also a ready solution from [JIDE](http://www.jidesoft.com/products/grids.htm), unfortunately it is not free. Here is for example `CellSpanTable`:

[image]

Comment: I've been using JIDE for years. The API is extremely rich, that is, if you can afford it. I believe they might have a student version. Not sure. Do a google for jidesoft.

Answer (score 11):

[MultiCellSpanTableExample](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/MultiSpanCellTableExample.htm) is fine, but it has a little problem that can become a huge problem if your table has too many columns. As you can see in the [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDu9F.png) given by tenorsax, apparently each table column has an extra pixel in their width. Those additional pixels add up, making each column more displaced than the last.

I could simply fix that by replacing the line:

```
cellFrame.width = aColumn.getWidth() + columnMargin;
```

with:

```
cellFrame.width = aColumn.getWidth() + columnMargin - 1;
```

I know nobody asked, but I hope this helps someone. :)

Comment: thanks! finding the fix before even discovering the problem is the best!

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom TableCellRenderer

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

public class HeaderRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
TableCellRenderer renderer;

public HeaderRenderer(JTable table) {
  renderer = table.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer();
}

@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int col) {

super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, col);
switch (col) {
case 0:
  setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 0, Color.LIGHT_GRAY));
break;
case 1:
  setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 0, 1, 1, Color.LIGHT_GRAY));
break;
default:
  setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, Color.LIGHT_GRAY));
break;
}
  return this;
}
}
```

[from oracle doc](https:////docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/SimpleTableDemoProject/src/components/SimpleTableDemo.java)

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

public class SimpleTableDemo extends JPanel {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public SimpleTableDemo() {
super(new GridLayout(1, 0));

String[] columnNames = { "First Name", "Last Name", "Sport", "# of Years", "Vegetarian" };

    Object[][] data = { { "Kathy", "Smith", "Snowboarding", new Integer(5), new Boolean(false) },{ "John", "Doe", "Rowing", new Integer(3), new Boolean(true) },{ "Sue", "Black", "Knitting", new Integer(2), new Boolean(false) },{ "Jane", "White", "Speed reading", new Integer(20), new Boolean(true) },    { "Joe", "Brown", "Pool", new Integer(10), new Boolean(false) } };

JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
TableCellRenderer myRenderer = new HeaderRenderer(table);
table.getTableHeader().setDefaultRenderer(myRenderer);
table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 70));
table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

add(scrollPane);
}

private static void createAndShowGUI() {
JFrame frame = new JFrame("SimpleTableDemo");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

SimpleTableDemo newContentPane = new SimpleTableDemo();
newContentPane.setOpaque(true);
frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
createAndShowGUI();
}
});
}
}
```