# Adding information row in middle of JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'd like to be able to add a row into the middle of a JTable that acts as an information or title bar for the data below it.  I'd like to do this multiple times within the JTable. Perfect example would be to show a row with the date of all the following entries.  I've searched over API and can't seem to find a solution.
Thanks!

I'm looking for the following which was found here
[JTable with varying number of columns per row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4147843/jtable-with-varying-number-of-columns-per-row)

However, I'd like the section title row to be fixed when scrolling horizontally

```
A1 Section Title Row With long Text  (FIXED WHEN SCROLLING HORIZONTALLY)
A2          B2          C2          D2
A3          B3          C3          D3
A4          B4          C4          D4
A5 Section Title Row With long Text (FIXED WHEN SCROLLING HORIZONTALLY)
A6          B6          C6          D6
A7 Section Title Row With long Text  (FIXED WHEN SCROLLING HORIZONTALLY)
A8          B8          C8          D8
A9          B9          C9          D9
```

Comment: *Perfect example would be to show a row with the date of all the following entries.* - Perfect example would be for you to give us an ascii representation of how you expect the data to be displayed. A JTable is designed to display rows of data. Each row should contain the same type of data and the same number of columns.

Comment: I updated question to be more clear.Thanks

Comment: Maybe something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21856733/how-to-merge-cell-in-defaulttablemodel-jtable/21977825#21977825

Comment: A JTable is not a spreadsheet.  You might be able to get something like what you want with a component sometimes referred to as an accordion.

Comment: camickr... that unfortunately wont allow the data in the information to stay put when user scrolls horizontally

Comment: Instead of making the information bar a separate row, Can I put an information label between rows somehow?